# forloop in table() in R

Tags: r, for-loop, data-manipulation

how can I loop over a table? Many thanks in advance.

```
    rst <- NULL
  for(i in 0:1) {
  rst[i] <-  table(mtcars$vs == [i] & mtcars$am == [i])["TRUE"]
}
rst
```

Expected answer; 12, 7

```
  table(mtcars$vs == 0 & mtcars$am == 0)["TRUE"]
  table(mtcars$vs == 1 & mtcars$am == 1)["TRUE"]
```

Comment: Try with `rst[i + 1] <-  table(mtcars$vs == i & mtcars$am == i)["TRUE"]`. In R indices of list, vectors, ... start at 1.

Comment: No loops are needed: `diag(table(mtcars[c("vs", "am")]))`.

Comment: As other commenters have indicated there's no need for a loop here.  In fact, a good rule of thumb when working in R is "If you're thinking of using a loop, there's almost certainly a better way of doing it".